# Unable to find electron app

Tags: javascript, angular, electron

I'm running through this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_vMChpZMCk&t=6s) on an Ubuntu 17.10 and when I run the build command `ng build --prod && electron .` the result is:

Error launching app
Unable to find Electron app at /home/ole/angular-electron

Cannot find module '/home/ole/angular-electron'

The app compiles fine, just the `electron .` step that is failing.  The `package.json` contents including the `main` attribute look like this:

```
  "name": "angular-electron",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "main.js",
```

I also tried running running the command as indicated in the first answer and this is the result:

```
    ole@mki:~/angular-electron$ ng build --prod && npm run electron
    Date: 2018-02-03T02:57:31.154Z
    Hash: a2a64f9c18abdabf8e6e
    Time: 25113ms
    chunk {0} polyfills.f20484b2fa4642e0dca8.bundle.js (polyfills) 59.4 kB [initial] [rendered]
    chunk {1} main.34c2037568943aee5abc.bundle.js (main) 152 kB [initial] [rendered]
    chunk {2} styles.9c0ad738f18adc3d19ed.bundle.css (styles) 79 bytes [initial] [rendered]
    chunk {3} inline.ef66fc99c35b976a47ae.bundle.js (inline) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]

    > angular-electron@0.0.0 electron /home/ole/Junk/angular-electron
    > electron .

    Error launching app
    Unable to find Electron app at /home/ole/Junk/angular-electron

    Cannot find module '/home/ole/Junk/angular-electron'
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! angular-electron@0.0.0 electron: `electron .`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the angular-electron@0.0.0 electron script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/ole/.npm/_logs/2018-02-03T02_57_32_025Z-debug.log
    ole@mki:~/Junk/angular-electron$ ng build --prod && npm run electron
    Date: 2018-02-03T02:59:37.741Z
    Hash: a2a64f9c18abdabf8e6e
    Time: 25083ms
    chunk {0} polyfills.f20484b2fa4642e0dca8.bundle.js (polyfills) 59.4 kB [initial] [rendered]
    chunk {1} main.34c2037568943aee5abc.bundle.js (main) 152 kB [initial] [rendered]
    chunk {2} styles.9c0ad738f18adc3d19ed.bundle.css (styles) 79 bytes [initial] [rendered]
    chunk {3} inline.ef66fc99c35b976a47ae.bundle.js (inline) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]

    > angular-electron@0.0.0 electron /home/ole/Junk/angular-electron
    > electron .

    Error launching app
    Unable to find Electron app at /home/ole/Junk/angular-electron

    Cannot find module '/home/ole/Junk/angular-electron'
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! angular-electron@0.0.0 electron: `electron .`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the angular-electron@0.0.0 electron script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/ole/.npm/_logs/2018-02-03T02_59_38_568Z-debug.log
    ole@mki:~/Junk/angular-electron$ ng build --prod && npm run electron .
    Date: 2018-02-03T03:01:35.087Z
    Hash: a2a64f9c18abdabf8e6e
    Time: 25017ms
    chunk {0} polyfills.f20484b2fa4642e0dca8.bundle.js (polyfills) 59.4 kB [initial] [rendered]
    chunk {1} main.34c2037568943aee5abc.bundle.js (main) 152 kB [initial] [rendered]
    chunk {2} styles.9c0ad738f18adc3d19ed.bundle.css (styles) 79 bytes [initial] [rendered]
    chunk {3} inline.ef66fc99c35b976a47ae.bundle.js (inline) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]

    > angular-electron@0.0.0 electron /home/ole/Junk/angular-electron
    > electron . "."

    Error launching app
    Unable to find Electron app at /home/ole/Junk/angular-electron

    Cannot find module '/home/ole/Junk/angular-electron'
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! angular-electron@0.0.0 electron: `electron . "."`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the angular-electron@0.0.0 electron script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/ole/.npm/_logs/2018-02-03T03_01_35_948Z-debug.log
```

Also tried running the electron command separately with `electron .`.  The result is the same.  It complains that it can't find `electron`.  Also tried running it from the `node_modules` directory like this:

ole@mki:~/angular-electron$ ./node_modules/electron/dist/electron .
Error launching app
Unable to find Electron app at /home/ole/angular-electron

Cannot find module '/home/ole/angular-electron'

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First install electron as a dev dependency like you have done with `npm i --save-dev electron`.  Then setup your build scripts like this:

```
"electron": "electron",
"electron-build": "ng build --prod && npm run electron"
```

The reason electron was not running is that it included a `.` in the electron run script like this `"electron": "electron .".

**EDIT:**

I believe it should be enough to do:

```
$ npm run electron
```

You don't have to edit your `package.json`. `npm` will try to find the `electron` in your `node_modules/.bin` then it will search in your global dependencies.

Try to avoid installing global `npm` dependencies. If you are installing a command line tool because your project needs it then always install it locally.

Comment: I tried the updated command but I'm still getting the same result.  Updated the question with a printout of my console.  Thoughts?

Comment: Ah, I am sorry about that. It looks like the `electron .` is being called from the `ng build` command. I would probably install `electron` globally. That should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks - hope to have it tested soon - ran into another issue while attempting the global install: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48593682/installing-electron-globally-on-ubuntu-with-npm

Comment: you don't need to install global, npm can find `electron` in `node_modules`. I think the problem is like @Michal said, so you should split into 2 seperate npm command: 1 for build, and another for start app

Comment: I broke it up into two commands and the result is still the same.  Updated the question with the results.

Comment: Simplified the question and reposted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48594344/using-electron-as-a-npm-dev-dependency-on-ubuntu

Comment: Did you try installing electron globally? :) You don't want to save it as local dev dependency.

Comment: @Michal i updated the answer, with the info from the associated questions and it works now.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using @angular/cli ~1.4.0, make sure `main.js` and `package.json` are in same folder.

```
<root>/src
      index.html
      main.ts
main.js
package.json
```

Comment: Worked for me. By habit the main.js landed in the /src folder when it actually was configured to be loaded from the root.