# Installing electron globally on Ubuntu with NPM

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu, npm, electron

Attempting to resolve [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48593290/unable-to-find-electron-app/48593349?noredirect=1#comment84184346_48593349) and getting the following error when installing electron globally with NPM:

```
    ole@mki:~/angular-electron$ sudo npm install electron -g 
    /usr/bin/electron -> /usr/lib/node_modules/electron/cli.js

    > electron@1.7.12 postinstall /usr/lib/node_modules/electron
    > node install.js

    /usr/lib/node_modules/electron/install.js:48
    throw err
    ^

    Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/electron/dist'
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! electron@1.7.12 postinstall: `node install.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the electron@1.7.12 postinstall script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/ole/.npm/_logs/2018-02-03T03_28_15_952Z-debug.log
```

Comment: have you tried `sudo -p mkdir /usr/lib/node_modules/electron` ?

Comment: I did.  It then complains about the ...electron/dist directory .... and if I create that it still complains that it can't create it.  It almost seems like electron is  not made for global install...

Comment: I wrote a tiny guide how to bypass this issue and install electron globally: https://donnikitos.com/install-electron-globally-on-linux/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [npm proposes](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions):

```
 mkdir ~/.npm-global
 npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
 export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
 source ~/.profile
```

By doing it this was you keep your global npm packages scoped within your user account, instead of shared between all the users in the computer. Even if you're the only user, this is a recommended behavior. :-)

Comment: Excellent!  That should help with a lot of other things as well.

Comment: Incidentally we were able to resolve electron using a local install as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48593290/unable-to-find-electron-app