# i m trying to use sudo npm install -g @angular/cli ....but it is giving error......is it because i used sudo apt-get autoremove command before

Tags: angular, ubuntu, angular-cli

```
pratik@pratik-Inspiron-15-3567:~$ npm install -g @angular/cli
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pratik/.npm/_logs/2018-02-03T06_48_18_710Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Although you could run the command again as root (or with `sudo`), it's a much better idea to fix the permissions of the `node_modules` folder using `chmod`

Comment: i tried with root also but was getting some error....and how to do with chmod

Comment: pratik@pratik-Inspiron-15-3567:~$ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli  
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY  
npm ERR! sha1-odSd75TE5aylzPHViBLkZo+sGdQ= integrity checksum   failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-odSd75TE5aylzPHViBLkZo+sGdQ= but got sha1-lvbMEJtMtkcsYYWrYFRaLokOi9o=. (570430 bytes)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pratik/.npm/_logs/2018-02-03T07_06_11_355Z-debug.log

Comment: that was using sudo

Comment: Very odd - I would probably reinstall npm or use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) (if you don't use it already)

Comment: Change the global npm package folder, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48596268/7434393