# can't install electron globally

Tags: ubuntu, npm, electron

I am trying to install electron globally , but I am facing this annoying error message

---

```
/home/tbh/.npm-global/bin/electron -> /home/tbh/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/electron/cli.js

> electron@2.0.8 postinstall /home/tbh/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/electron
> node install.js

/home/tbh/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/electron/install.js:54
  throw err
  ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/tbh/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/electron/dist'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! electron@2.0.8 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the electron@2.0.8 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

---

I have tried several things including running this with sudo and changing NPM configuration accrediting to this Question on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48593682/installing-electron-globally-on-ubuntu-with-npm)
But nothing worked for me
if anybody needs the log for this problem you can find it here [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xw3yJzksfk/)
PS: my OS is Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Did you try `sudo npm install -g electron`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try installing with: `sudo npm install -g electron --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root` instead.

Source: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10604#issuecomment-333368230

Comment: No problem :), always happy to help