# Using electron as a npm dev dependency on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu, npm, electron

On Ubuntu 17.10 I'm installing and running electron like this:

```
    ole@mki:~/angular-electron$ npm i --save-dev electron

    > electron@1.7.12 postinstall /home/ole/angular-electron/node_modules/electron
    > node install.js

    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

    + electron@1.7.12
    updated 1 package in 19.956s
    ole@mki:~/angular-electron$ electron
    electron: command not found
```

Ubuntu cannot find the electron command after install.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running `npm i --save-dev electron` the package will be installed in `/home/ole/angular-electron/node_modules/electron` (as you can see). To execute the binary you need to run `/home/ole/angular-electron/node_modules/.bin/electron` or `$(npm bin)/electron`.

I propose that you'll add a script in your `package.json` to run electron, for example:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "electron"
}
```

npm will then automatically look into `node_modules/.bin`.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a little bit confusing but in general, there are 2 ways how to run npm packages.

1. You can install the package globally `npm install
   your-package-name -g`
2. You can install the package locally `npm install
   your-package-name` and then run it from
   `/node_modules/.bin/electron`

If you install your package locally you have also two options how to run the package from command line:

1. Directly from `node_modules` like this: `../node_modules/.bin/electron`
2. You can create a `script` command in your

`package.json:`

```
"scripts": {
  "your-script-name": "electron"
}
```

then if you run `npm run your-script-name` `npm` will first look in the `.bin` directory and if it finds `electron` it will run it. Otherwise it will look at your global dependencies.

However, it is important not to forget that this command:

```
"your-script-name": "do-something && electron"
```

will also run `electron` globally. If you want to run electron locally you can either split the command into two separate commands or change `electron` to `npm run electron` like this:

```
"your-script-name": "do-something && npm run electron"
```